# How do Laravel, Meteor, Underscore, and AngularJS generate their API docs?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, meteor, underscore.js

Underscore uses docco for annotated source code. But what about the API docs? How do these projects generate their respective API docs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Laravel uses: http://apigen.org/